# How to set personal interval to check data usage?

Tags: settings, data-monitoring

On my Nexus 4 with stock Lollipop, I can check the usage data month by month, but my subscription is every 30 days (around the 15th).

New contracts last 28 days, so there is more difference between real interval and a month.

Is it possible to set a personal interval (the start and the during) to check it?

Comment: As far as I remember, even there is no setting to change the interval since JellyBean, and I'm afraid it's impossible to do it on stock ROM. Most possible, you have to use 3rd-party apps.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation in this sub-stackexchange, so I will answer instead of commenting.

This options is not available in Android (up to this date), but there is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66034) (which you can star*), which has unfortunately been marked *obsolete* with no reason whatsoever. Maybe it can be rediscovered if enough people star it.

P.s.: [Here is a similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=45426) which has not been marked obsolete (yet).

Edit: Another trick (which does not really give you the desired effect) might be to use an app from your provider (these often show you how much data you have left).

*Makes it more likely that it might be implemented at some point.

Comment: There appears to be [another listing of the same issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23676) (with a few more stars).

Answer (score 2):

Go to data usage in setting, and click the drop-down that says some interval (5 Dec-4 Nov etc) and choose "Change cycle..." to change the start date.

Comment: It works for the starting day, but I am not able to set the during (30 days is not a month, but there are also week subscriptions)

Comment: I disagree with -1 vote because it reply to a part of the question

Answer (score -2):

I found the "Change cycle" option today.
It's at the bottom of the drop-down

I had to scroll past every month from 2014 to 1970 (~520 months)

[image]

Comment: I am not able to find this setting

Comment: It's the same as [saloalv's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/89880/44325) actually.

Comment: Andrew T, it's not the same answer

Comment: Ale, I had to scroll past 1970

Comment: Johgru, if it isn't the same answer as saloalv's, please add some additional information.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot? Maybe it helps me to understand how to find this setting

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Better?

Comment: @Ale I have added a screenshot and some more info

Comment: @johgru this setting let me to modify the starting day, not the duration of the interval

Comment: @Ale I'm sorry! I missunderstood your question